# What exactly is the datatype input into a DATETIME value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-format, string, data

I am trying to get data from a PLC directly into a MySQL 8.0 database (using MySQL Workbench). I need to know what data type the input value is for a column set to `DATETIME` so I can send in the right format.

**Actual question: I assume it's string, because when I manually input values using and `INSERT`, the value has to be in ' '. Is this a stupid assumption on my part?**

When the output of my PLC is a string and the datatype of my column is `DATETIME`, what I read from a `SELECT` in my DB is completely wrong : '1905-07-13 00:00:00' instead of '2021-04-30 08:51:30'. However, if I write it in the DB column set to be of type `VARCHAR`, it's written correctly, but not usable for my next app. So if I then change the column to `DATETIME`, everything works great, but that's super impractical and I can be changing the datatype of my column every time I need to add to the DB.

Another assumption I'm making here is that the input datatype is what's causing this problem, but as it is now, `DATE` and `DATETIME` are not supported by the driver I'm using, so maybe it's just wishful thinking on my part that any of this will work at all.

Note: Please do migrate this if it's off topic, wasn't really sure if it was a best fit here or stack overflow...

Second Note: The only way I have found to make this work is to write into the DB as a VARCHAR and then use CONVERT(,DATETIME) in my app, but it feels weird that I can't just write a date in my DB for some reason.....

Comment: Show us an example of the _text_ that comes from the PLC.  It is probably not compatible with `DATETIME`, but can be converted with an @variable and a function call.

Comment: I get '2021-04-30 08:51:30' from the PLC

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the `LOAD` statement, and a sample line from the file.

Comment: I'm not using a load statement. I'm using KepSerververEx and the Data logger plugin which writes in the base without me doing anything. There isn't a file I'm loading, it's literally just the date right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide the value as string literal or as a numeric literal.

Possible formats are described in [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Alternatively you may provide the data in any custom format and apply [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to it in INSERT query with according parsing pattern.

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c623fda80ffd10c6a66f9805a764047)